Can $n=7$ padlocks interlock in a way that opening any $m=3$ of them unlock them?
On the left we have a door with multiple padlocks. This is an example of an AND logic gate type arrangement using padlocks:  Only by unlocking all of them, can you open the door.  The image on the right could also be extended if the bar on the left half had more locks (imagine extending its left half that has two padlocks to have instead 30 of them in a row).
 
Here is an example of an OR logic gate type arrangement using padlocks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=babjuKDwQls and also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdKKwJ7T7yc
Opening any one of them  opens the latch.


In those examples so far, the locks do not interact with each other directly. However, you can also interlock padlocks with each other. Such as the following:


So a question naturally arises of which arrangements can be made that are only opened when some of the locks are unlocked.
This reminded me of the Fano Plane where you have similar restrictions for objects and their relationships.

Is there a solution to the original question (7 padlocks where any 3 unlock them)?
More generally, how can we use combinatorial design or results from knot theory to solve this kind of question?
An answer to this question may clarify the connections (or distinctions) between those fields.
Note: The latch can be thought as an extra lock that is said to be open when it can be removed after unlocking the necessary padlocks.
Note: here is a similar problem that allows multiple locks per person, but here we are assuming one lock per person and instead letting the complexity happen in the arrangement of the locks instead of in the number of locks.

It appears to me that all of your examples are OR gates.

Ah. My oversight. Let me find the correct AND one.

I'm surprised that the second example is an OR and not an AND. I couldn't see what made it work, but it seemed quite complicated.

Thank you for catching that. I found a suitable example to illustrate the AND one but it is not as elegant. You could also think of multiple locks inserted in the same slot for an 'and'.

Yes, AND is pretty easy.

isn't it the point of the Borromean rings that you don't need to undo all three?

I removed the part about Borromean rings. It was there because I found Brunnian links and it seemed relevant. Good catch.

well I think Brunnian links are relevant in that (if you assume sufficiently bendy padlocks) any Brunnian link will make what you call an OR gate. It could be interesting to investigate if there are ways to link together several small Brunnian links to achieve the $m;n$ scheme you are interested in, but I don't know offhand how you might do it.

The Tayhope system actually allows opening the gate after any lock is removed.
Each lock is attached to a metal plate that can be removed when unlocked.
If you attach this assembly to the swinging part of a gate, the removable plate on one end also fits in a slot attached to the stationary part. Removing any one of the removable plates allows you to collect the rest of them in the portion of the assembly that doesn't engage the slot, and the gate opens.
In theory, this is easily extended to opening the gate when any $m$ of $n$ locks are removed. Simply make the slot on the stationary part of the gate long enough to contact $m$ of the removable plates. When $m$ plates are removed, and only then, it is possible to collect the remaining $n - m$ plates in the part of the assembly that does not engage the slot, and the gate can be opened.
In practical terms there may be structural concerns with a very long slot, but that takes more than just mathematics to discuss.

I had not considered length when thinking about the problem. You are correct, you could extend this idea if unlocking a lock gives leeway to a fixed distance for a latch system requiring another extensible distance moved to be unlocked.

The Tayhope lock pictured is an OR lock. Each individual padlock is attached to a plate, and when any one is removed, the latch mechanism has room to slide open. To modify this, we can make it so that it ORs together not individual locks, but all possible combinations of 3 locks ANDed together.
There are 7C3 or 35 possible combinations of 3 locks, so instead of 7 locks on 7 plates with 1 hole each, we need 7 locks on 35 plates with 3 holes each. Each lock passes through 15 of the plates. Every combination of 3 locks being removed will allow one of the 35 plates to be removed and the latch to open.
This is a bit more complicated than @DavidK's solution, and doesn't scale very well with more locks. That said, the downside of having to physically enumerate every combination of locks that will open the latch with its own plate could be a benefit in some cases - you could exclude specific combinations instead of allowing any 3, or also allow certain combinations of fewer locks to open the latch. Using a system like this to explicitly enumerate all valid combinations might be useful in certain applications, but might be overkill for "any 3".
